# How to unselect a field after a second click after it has been selected on the first click

Tags: javascript

i got a code here that i need to modify, the thing is this code works well for the first click,as the entire field becomes highlighted however this is a problem for users who want to manually type the url after the "http://" (the problem is the http:// remains highlighted, so the user replaces that with whatever he enters in the field) instead of pasting the entire link. Thanks

```
function SelectURL(field)
{

    field.focus();
    field.select(); 
}


 <input name="URL" type="text" value="http://" maxlength="255" OnClick="SelectURL(this.form.URL)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

store some value in alt attribute, and check it in your function.

When user clicks first time, set alt to '1', for instance.

Next time you will see that alt attribute is present, so you should remove focus. And set alt to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use the onFocus event rather than the OnClick event.

It will only fire when the textbox gains focus